# Mobile app development

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way by which I can develop an app which can be connected only to the WLAN of the college and the app should be restricted from using mobile data and other wireless networks.

Comment: show some code here

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you mean an app that can access data only through college WLAN? Then yes
2. If you mean an app that restrict user's phone from connecting to any other source of internet, then NO.

**The user has the highest power on deciding what he wants to do with his phone, [apps requires permission from users](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/index.html)**

If it is case 1, You can try checking whether it is using WIFI or data:

```
public static String checkNetworkStatus(final Context context) {

        String networkStatus = "";

        // Get connect mangaer
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)  
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // check for wifi
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        // check for mobile data
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if( wifi.isAvailable() ) {
            networkStatus = "wifi";
        } else if( mobile.isAvailable() ) {
            networkStatus = "mobileData";
        } else {
            networkStatus = "noNetwork";
        }

        return networkStatus;

}  // end checkNetworkStatus
```

Then get the wifi name, and compare that to your college wifi name:

```
public String getWifiName(Context context) {
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
       WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
       if (wifiInfo != null) {
          DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState());
          if (state == DetailedState.CONNECTED || state == DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
              return wifiInfo.getSSID();
          }
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Happy Coding